# Trying to get jquery hover to work on array of images

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, hover

I'm having problems with a function and not sure what the answer is. The function I've written is as follows:

```
function display (array) {
for (i=0, max = array.length; i<max; i++){  
    var galleryTitle=array[i][3];
    var gallerySize=array[i][2];
    var galleryDate=array[i][1];
    var galleryDescription=array[i][4];

    $('#container').append(
        '<div id="'+array[i][0]+'" style="position: absolute;  left:'+array[i][6]+'px; top: '+array[i][7]+'px;"><a href="#"><img src=images/'+array[i][5]+'></a></div>'
    );

    $("#"+i).hover( 
        function () { 
            $(this).append('<div id="description"><b>Title: </b>'+galleryTitle+'<br /><b>Images: </b>'+gallerySize+'<br /><b>Date: </b>'+galleryDate+'<br /><br />'+galleryDescription+'</div>');
        },      
        function () { 
            $(this).find("div:last").remove(); 
        } 
    );
}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is cause a css box to appear with information about a thumbnail in it, whenever that particular thumbnail is hovered over.

The information and, indeed, the urls of the thumbnails are stored in an array at the start of the script.

The code above works and the css box appears *except* whichever thumb I hover over, only information about the thumbnail identified by the last iteration (is that the right word?) of the for loop appears.

I understand why this is happening (ie, the loop is finished by the time the hover statement comes into being and so 'i' will always be set to the last value) but I can't work out what to do about it. I've tried inserting get element by id calls within the first div but this just seems to knock out the entire script.

I'm happy to post the script in its entirety up here if that helps but thought I;d just hit you all with the bare minimum first.

Any ideas where I should be heading on this?

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net....hard to follow the wordy description

Comment: $("#"+i) ---> IDs cannot start with numbers!

Comment: In **HTML** less than **5** IDs cannot start with numbers... =)

Comment: One more thing about your code... always try to avoid manipulating the  DOM in a cycle. Just add the string to an array and then `.join('')` it to get the final string. You can really improve that code by keeping the array in memory (or in the `.data()` attribute of jQuery), and then, instead of binding one event handler per child, just use the `.delegate()` over the parent. This scenario will absolutely improve your code and its performance.

Comment: Thanks for that. As is probably pretty obvious from the code I'm very new to jquery and am feeling my way with it. Will take that on board and look into things in more depth when I've finished this current project. Cheers, Stef.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your `for` loop with jQuery's `$.each()` function it should solve the problem, not because there's anything magical about `$.each()` but just because that encapsulates each iteration of the loop in a separate function call which means your variables `galleryTitle` and the others will be captured in separate closures and thus retain their correct values after the loop is finished. (If you're not sure how closures work the simplest explanation applicable to this code is that the inner functions you are passing to `.hover()` continue to have access to the variables within their containing scope even after the function that is that containing scope exits.) Try:

```
function display (array) {
    $.each(array, function(i, val){ 
        var galleryTitle=val[3],
            gallerySize=val[2],
            galleryDate=val[1],
            galleryDescription=val[4];

        $('#container').append(
            '<div id="'+array[i][0]+'" style="position: absolute;  left:'+array[i][6]+'px; top: '+array[i][7]+'px;"><a href="#"><img src=images/'+array[i][5]+'></a></div>'
        );

        $("#"+i).hover( 
            function () { 
                $(this).append('<div id="description"><b>Title: </b>'+galleryTitle+'<br /><b>Images: </b>'+gallerySize+'<br /><b>Date: </b>'+galleryDate+'<br /><br />'+galleryDescription+'</div>');
            },      
            function () { 
                $(this).find("div:last").remove(); 
            } 
        );
    });
}
```

Note that the `$.each()` function calls the function you provide with two parameters, the current "loop" index and the current value from the array element at that index. This means that within the function you can replace `array[i]` with `val` (or whatever you call that parameter - I've called it `val`) - though `array[i]` will work too: I've changed the first few so you can see what it would look like...

Comment: You Sir, are a magical and beautiful human being and I love you xxxxx

Comment: Seriously, this has been doing my head in for about 2 weeks so genuine and heartfelt thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I don't recommend replacing all `for` loops with `$.each()` because plain `for` loops are more efficient, but where you need closures to keep the values from each iteration it is the easiest solution and neater than adding your own immediately-invoked anonymous function inside the `for` loop.